Is it possible to found a optimal polynomial-time solvable algorithm for graphs with 2 disjoint path of 4 vertices?
Currently, i am working on developing algorithm for graphs with 2P4(2 disjoint path of 4 vertices).
However, i found that most of the research paper working on H-free graph, recently have a paper like 2p4,C5 -free graph 3-coloring solve. Is it possible to turning it as a solution for a optimal algorithm?
I tried to search for existing algorithm, but as NP-compete problem. They're also not guaranteed for solving it. And most algorithm like greedy is like finding the upper limit of coloring the graph. I am pretty confused is the problem really solvable.
